# How can i Linking the Protocol Buffer(C++) into the Xcode

Tags: hyperlink, protocol-buffers

I added the `protobuf` class `"xxx.pb.h"`,`"xxx.pb.cc"` in Project.
I added a path`"/usr/local/include"` in `Header Search Paths`,
and added a path`"/usr/local/lib"` in `Library Search Paths.`

Now I encountered a problem,
The following error at Build:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libprotoc.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libprotoc.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()", referenced from:
      protobuf_AssignDesc_person_2eproto() in person.pb.o
"google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int)", referenced from:
      protobuf_AddDesc_person_2eproto() in person.pb.o
"google::protobuf::MessageFactory::generated_factory()", referenced from:
      protobuf_AssignDesc_person_2eproto() in person.pb.o
```

...
...

```
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for google::protobuf::Message", referenced from:
      google::protobuf::Message::Message() in person.pb.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDcC5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned in this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279656/1383704

There are a few pitfalls here and there, for which you may check [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15246414/1383704) for the same qn.

These were the steps I followed differently

1. instead of giving header search path till google directory, i gave the search path till the "src/" directory
2. In whichever you import your `xxx.pb.h` you have to rename the `.m` to `.mm`

In Xcode 4.5 i was still getting some linker errors :

> symbols not found for architecture i386

Because of this I wasn't able to run on simulator. But the code will run on actual device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！
My method is wrong.
Proper steps should be so:
1. you need to download the protocolbuf2.3.0 version, to create " xxx.pb.h " and " xxx.pb.cc " file.

2. don't add the path in the <Library Search Paths>, just add "/usr/local/include"(This is the default installation path) in <Header Search Paths>.

3.<Link Binary With Libraties> is not to add " libprotobuf.a " and " libprotoc.a " library. To add " libz.dylib ", " libxml2.dylib " and " libprotobuf.dylib ".

Comment: you can work with latest protobuf too. i.e. version 2.5. 
Also, I followed the steps mentioned in the answer and it worked perfectly for me. I never had to add the lib search paths.