# Adding C++ Google Protocol Buffers to iOS app is failing to load headers from Header Search Path

Tags: ios, xcode, protocol-buffers

I am following this post: [Google protocol buffers on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277576/google-protocol-buffers-on-ios)

I copied the Google Folder and Config.h into my project.

I have finished everything, but the problem I am having is to do with this step: "add the directory of google headers to your additional include directories"

I added the Google folder to my Header Search Path & User Header Search Paths. I used this: "$(SRCROOT)"/google  recursive

No matter what I do, the compiler can not find the Google headers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont give the path till **google/** ... give the path till **src/**

Navigate to your protocol buffer's src folder and just drag and drop the src folder to "Header Search Paths" in XCode buld settings. That should do it.

Comment: Thank-you. This is the solution. You must link to src/