# Use C++ Protobuf in XCode8 IOS app

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build an IOS app in XCode8 with some existing C++ code that uses Google Protobuf, but can't get it to work.

I tried using CocoaPods as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470451/5135283) and in other places.

Also tried some building scripts: [script1](https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/9487468ae3375d0db0cc), [script2](https://gist.github.com/Gubarev/a5a56135c9ff814b0117).

In all of the tries I eventually got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 
  "google_public::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, google_public::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", 
  "google_public::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringFallback(char const*, int, google_public::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation, char const*)",
  "google_public::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)",
```

With a list of some more protobuf implementation functions that are missing.

Is there any other way to compile/use the protobuf library XCode for IOS app?

Comment: Since the functions in questions are all ones that use `std::string`, I wonder if this has to do with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124264/undefined-reference-to-googleprotobufinternalempty-string-abicxx11/30175210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I had multiple versions of protobuf over my system from all the tries, and I accidentally mixed different versions for the includes, the lib, and the protoc generated files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate C++ code you have to change the file ending for the C++ code from .cpp to .mm. Have you done this?

Comment: Sure. The C++ code compiles and runs well, until the Protobuf usage.