# Cardboard QR Decode

Tags: google-cardboard

tl;dr: Is there a way to get Cardboard's calibration data without parsing through Google's protocol buffers?
I need to access Cardboard viewer's lens data, coefficients etc. to do proper undistortion calculation.
I contacted two Cardboard viewer manufactures and both had no idea what the values are and pointed me to contact google, since they used googles calibration.
[As discribed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658751/cardboard-qr-scanning-without-unity-sdk/35131379#35131379) you can decode the QR code by c++ parsing it through Google's protocol buffers, but I am currently not in a c++ dev enviroment and crunching through the doc to get the manufacturers calibration is very time consuming for just a bunch of coefficients. Is there a better way?

Comment: FWIW, the Protocol Buffers format is supported by numerous other programming languages besides C++.

Comment: I had a hunch, that was the case, still, crunching a whole doc just to get the base64 encoded string is painful. Would make deving for cardboard outside the google eco system a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone build a Webpage (https://lisa-wolfgang.github.io/vrEmbed/tools/google_profile_decode.html) that decodes the Google Cardboard Links into JSON using googles javascript protocol buffer library. (If you use the short URL, leave out the `http://`)

I used it to get out the data for a project.

Comment: Holy Moly, this is gold! 
Many thanks, works flawlessly.

Comment: broken link :-(

Comment: Replaced link with a live one from a github fork, tested with the long url decode, works

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didnt work for me so I scanned the QR code with a reader, got a short goo.gl URL.

I ran this through https://www.expandurl.net/ and got a longer link that just points to  the app store to download Cardboard app like this:
http://google.com/cardboard/app?p=ALONGSTRINGOFCHARACTERS

I just needed this to set my Unity project's Cardboard profile automatically so that the QR code doesnt have to be scanned on every device:

`GvrCardboardHelpers.SetViewerProfile("http://google.com/cardboard/cfg?p=ALONGSTRINGOFCHARACTERS");`

You can Base64 decode that long string of characters (the 'p' parameter) to get the coefficients, but it's encoded in a binary format.

Reverse engineering the Cardboard profile generator (https://vr.google.com/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/) may help decode exactly which variables are what, but unfortunately it seems broken currently.