# Google Protobufs in iOS app crashing at GPBDescriptor

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, protocol-buffers

This one is a real head-scratcher...

**PART ONE**

We have a swift iOS application with different targets for Dev and Prod (normal stuff).

We've incorporated **Google Protobufs** into it for one of our latest features. This was done using Google's J2ObjC library and the `pod 'Protobuf', '= 3.11.4'` pod. (Our `.proto` files were made with v3.11.4).

Running our Dev target works fine (mostly, see Part Two). Running our Prod target **crashes in the constructor of any GPBMessage object.**

It crashes within the `+ (GPBDescriptor *)descriptor` function of the `pbobc.m` file of our message object...eventually getting to this error within `GPBDescriptor.m`

Line:

```
enumHandling_.enumDescriptor_ = coreDesc->dataTypeSpecific.enumDescFunc();
```

Error:

```
(lldb) po coreDesc->dataTpeSpecific
error: <user expression 2>:1:11: no member named 'dataTpeSpecific' in 'GPBMessageFieldDescription'
coreDesc->dataTpeSpecific
~~~~~~~~  ^
```

What's weird is this crashes in Prod and not Dev. Combing through both targets' Build Settings...they're *identical*. Build Phases are the same, Build Rules are the same, Plists are basically the same...

I don't know what else to check.

**PART TWO**

There is one GPB message that crashes on init in both our Dev and Prod targets. (We can run without it, so I've commented it out during development.)
The difference between this message and the others is that this one is a list of enums.
It crashes on the same line. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Thank you ***SO MUCH*** in advance! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course immediately after I post the question I find the answer...
[Google protocol buffers on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277576/google-protocol-buffers-on-ios/18111371#18111371)

Needed to add `-fno-objc-arc` to every `...pbobjc.m` file in the `Compile Sources` of `Build Phases`.
I had already done this for a few files in Dev, hence the (very subtle!) difference.